# Asp.net how to Delete specific List Items from a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a model which contains a list and I need to remove/delete all items from the model based on the `MarkedForDeletion` value.

So far I've tried the following but this is not valid, I would prefer to not loop through the records using a for loop.

#### Models cs

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool MarkedForDeletion { get; set; )
}
```

#### Attempted Solution (not a valid statement)

```
CategoryModel.Items.Where(x => x.MarkedForDeletion = true).Remove;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8) which will remove all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate?

```
CategoryModel.Items.RemoveAll(x => x.MarkedForDeletion);
```

Comment: I had tried variations with remove and removeall but can't have tried that as this works now. Thanks

Comment: @Fletch: Glad to hear that, happy codding..! :)